# Is it better to bind/unbind events or to use a conditional (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Ok, this is a performance question I guess.

I have a slider with two navigation links (next and previous) and when the slider gets to the end of the row I am currently unbinding the next button, then binding again when it goes in the other direction. I am performing the same operation for the next button, but reversed.

the code for the next button would look something like this

```
if (at end of slider) {
  nextBtn.unbind("click")
} else if (not already bound) {
  nextBtn.bind("click",clickHandler)
}
```

So... Is it better do it this way or to have a conditional in the click handler to check for  `$.data(nextBtn,"state","on")` or `$.data(nextBtn,"state","off")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using an actual `<button>` then you can just set the `disabled` attribute to `true` and not have to worry about anything in your event handler, since the event will never be triggered.  This also has the added benefit of adding a visual aide to tell the user that the button in question is no longer functional (which you should be doing regardless of the chosen button representation).

Otherwise, I usually keep with the mindset of staying out the DOM as much as possible, and that includes bind and unbinding events.  With this in mind, I would bind the events once, and check whatever condition you have within the event handler.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps (on reflection) button was a poor choice of words.  It's actually a dynamically created link so has no disabled state.  I take your point though. I'll take a look at trying to use a conditional for this, though using $.bind to test on probably isn't a goer either

Answer (score 2):

I would say the conditional statement.

Simply put every time you bind and unbind an event from what I gather jquery has to create and manage an entire new object.